# Scala arrays and parameterized types

Tags: arrays, generics, scala, types

I'm trying to define a generic class that takes a parameterized type T and then use the type in an Array definition in the class. I wrote the following which I thought seemed like it should work

```
class MyClass[T] {

  val myarr:Array[T] = new Array[T](10)

}
```

But the compiler complains with the following

- can't find the class manifest for element type T
- value newArray is not a member of Null

Anyone know whats going on here and what its not happy about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler needs to know how to instantiate things of type T.  In the traditional Java way of handling generics through type erasure, this cannot reasonably be done; the compiler just says, "Hey, I don't know what T is, so I don't feel so great about allowing you to instantiate a T like that."  In Scala, however, there is a word-around for this: manifests.  In order to include the manifest for T, just change the first line of that code to

```
class MyClass[T : Manifest] {
```

That's it.